# Replace composed unicode characters

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with precomposed unicode characters. [Here's wikipedia page about it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) I have got a word like "Åström", but accents aren't in the alphabet of this language. I want to get rid of them, but don't know how - I've tried copying and pasting the characters(worked for some before - probably they weren't composed), but this doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: What is your desired output? Decomposed characters? Just the base characters with accents stripped?

Comment: My goal is to find base characters without accents, yes. I want to get rid of accents.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Åström` has *decomposed* unicode characters, not *precomposed* ones:

(I'm assuming the current locale uses UTF-8 and those characters entered on the command line use UTF-8 encoding here (I've copy-pasted them from a browser using UTF-8)).

```
$ printf %s Åström | uconv -x any-name
\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A}\N{COMBINING RING ABOVE}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER S}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER T}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER R}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O}\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER M}
```

Note the *Combining diacritics above*. Pre-composed ones would be:

```
$ printf %s Åström | uconv -x nfkc | uconv -x any-name
\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER S}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER T}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER R}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS}\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER M}
```

Those pre-composed characters, contrary to the combining accents are present in iso8859-1 or iso8859-15. So if that's the intended destination character set, you could do:

```
$ printf %s Åström | uconv -x nfkc -t iso-8859-1
```

To convert the characters that can be converted, approximate the other ones:

```
$ printf %s 'Åström й' | uconv -x nfkc | iconv -t iso-8859-5//TRANSLIT
Astrom <0xd9>
```

(й is in the iso-8859-5 charset, so is converted to its representation there (0xd9 byte), but not Å, or ö which are then converted to a `A` and `o` approximation).

If you mean that your input has a combination of decomposed characters (like those `Å` and `ö`) and pre-composed ones (like `й`) and you want to keep the precomposed ones, but discard the combining characters in the decomposed ones, then you can do:

```
$ printf %s 'Åström й' | uconv -x '[:Nonspacing Mark:]>'
Astrom й
```

Note that there are two characters in Unicode with a `Å` visual representation: U+212B (Ångström) and U+00C5 (A with ring above). `nfkc` will convert U+212B to U+00C5.

If you want to remove all the diacritics, you can try:

```
$ printf %s Åström | iconv -t us//TRANSLIT
Astrom
```

(beware that some implementations of `iconv` may approximate the accents with adjacent `"` or `'`... characters)

Or:

```
$ printf %s Åström | uconv -x nfd -c -t us
Astrom
```

(decompose, convert to ASCII, dropping characters that can't be converted like combining accents).

Or:

```
$ printf %s Åström | uconv -x "::nfd;[:Nonspacing Mark:]>;"
Astrom
```

(decompose, drop all non-spacing marks)

Or:

```
$ printf %s Åström | uconv -x Latin-ASCII
Astrom
```

(ASCII transliteration for characters in the Latin script).

`uconv` is an utility from the [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/). On Debian and derivatives, you find it in the `icu-devtools` package.

Comment: What happened here? I see the ring over the `s` and the umlaut above the `m`. Is my browser wrong, or do others see it as well? (Using Firefox 44.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to remove diacritics; actually I don't know what diacritics would be, since I'm dealing with Cyrillic - so и and й are fine and different letters, but и with ` above it would be wrong.

Comment: @jknappen, that's a bug in your browser or rendering library (my browser (iceweasel on Debian) has the same bug, `chromium` doesn't).

Comment: @MatthewRock, you need to clarify what is fine and what isn't. `й` is in iso-8859-5, is that the charset your characters need to be present in? Would `iconv -t nfc -t iso-8859-5` work for you?

Comment: Yeah, I might have been unclear. I am using utf-8, and I want Cyrillic alphabet. Apart from that, I don't have much more requirements.

Comment: @MatthewRock, still unclear. Do you want that `Åström` to be converted to `А̊стрӧм` (latin characters converted to  cyrillic) or `Астром` (cyrillic, diacritics removed) or just removed as they are all latin characters?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I couldn't copy the characters, that's why I referenced to example from Wikipedia. Sorry for that. I am operating on Cyrillic words, so there's no need for conversion. The accents can only be found on cyrillic characters. I want to convert cyrillic with accents to cyrillic without accents.

Comment: @MatthewRock, but `й` (also й) has a _breve_ accent and you said you didn't want it removed. How do you determine what accents are OK, and which ones are not?

Comment: @MatthewRock, would `uconv -x '::nfkc;[:Nonspacing Mark:]>;'` work for you? (drop accents after canonical composition, so that characters that don't have a pre-composed form have their accent shaved of)

Answer (score 1):

There is a perl module Text::Unaccent available from CPAN for your purpose:

http://search.cpan.org/~ldachary/Text-Unaccent-1.08/Unaccent.pm

A sample perl script (working from STDIN to STDOUT) may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Text::Unaccent;
while ($zeile = <STDIN>)
{
   print STDOUT unac_string("UTF-8", $zeile);
}
```

Comment: How can I get it and use it?

Comment: There is a download link in the upper right part of the page I quoted.

Comment: @MatthewRock: To use it, write a small perl script reading your input file line by line, converting the line to unaccented and write them out again.

Comment: I might have been unclear - I am completely unfluent in Perl. Now since I am a programmer it's not an issue for me to do 10-minute research to write this script, but right now your answer is link-only - providing code snippet would both make it full answer, and help others who are not programmers, but stumble upon similar problem.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I used is to use `Emacs`. I open the file, find the part with accents, copy a character with accent and one character before the accent. I go to the beginning of file, run `M-x replace-string`, paste what I copied, go to the beginning of the minibuffer, delete the character that was before, and run the command.

I figured that the accent was more like a pre-character, so by copying both the character I wanted and character before, I ensured to copy everything I wanted.